# How can I find where the scss files are declared in nativescript drawer navigation template

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am using the nativescript drawer navigation template as the basis for my app.

The template works correctly until I add my login page.

Now I am getting an error from sass-loader plugin that the "$page-icon-color" variable is undefined.

The styling is separated into "_app-common.scss" and "_app-variables.scss"

Does anyone know where the link between the app-common and app-variable files is?

I have tried deleting the node-modules, hooks and platforms folders then running `tns install` at the app root folder

Here is the Device Console log

> LOG from device Galaxy S8: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Error
>   calling module function  Error: Module build failed (from
>   ../node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
>
> undefined
>                ^
>        Undefined variable: "$page-icon-color".
>        in C:\Users\chris\Documents\EAMS-Prototype-Asset-Survey-App\PrototypeAssetSurveyAppDrawer\src_app-common.scss
>   (line 10, column 16) File:
>   "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bundle.js, line:
>   26, column: 0
>
> StackTrace:   Frame: function:'ZoneAwareError',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js',
>   line: 1298, column: 31    Frame: function:'./_app-common.scss',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bundle.js',
>   line: 26, column: 7   Frame: function:'**webpack_require**',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js',
>   line: 751, column: 30     Frame: function:'fn',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js',
>   line: 121, column: 20     Frame: function:'',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bundle.js',
>   line: 418, column: 22     Frame: function:'./login/login.component.ts',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bundle.js',
>   line: 423, column: 2  Frame: function:'**webpack_require**',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js',
>   line: 751, column: 30     Frame: function:'fn',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js',
>   line: 121, column: 20     Frame: function:'./app/app-routing.module.ts',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bundle.js',
>   line: 61, column: 80  Frame: function:'**webpack_require**',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js',
>   line: 751, column: 30     Frame: function:'fn',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js',
>   line: 121, column: 20     Frame: function:'./app/app.module.ts',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bundle.js',
>   line: 208, column: 77     Frame: function:'**webpack_require**',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js',
>   line: 751, column: 30     Frame: function:'fn',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js',
>   line: 121, column: 20     Frame: function:'',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bundle.js',
>   line: 436, column: 73     Frame: function:'./main.ts',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bundle.js',
>   line: 503, column: 30     Frame: function:'**webpack_require**',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js',
>   line: 751, column: 30     Frame: function:'checkDeferredModules',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js',
>   line: 44, column: 23  Frame: function:'webpackJsonpCallback',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js',
>   line: 31, column: 19  Frame: function:'',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bundle.js',
>   line: 2, column: 57   Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1,
>   column: 266
>
> Error: Module build failed (from
>   ../node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
>
> undefined
>                ^
>        Undefined variable: "$page-icon-color".
>        in C:\Users\chris\Documents\EAMS-Prototype-Asset-Survey-App\PrototypeAssetSurveyAppDrawer\src_app-common.scss
>   (line 10, column 16)  at com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)     at
>   com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:663)   at
>   com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:655)     at
>   com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
>     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1154)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6222)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:237)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1785)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)

Comment: The template has platform specific SCSS files (`app.[android|ios].scss`), which would import `_app-common.scss` and `_app-variables.scss` and it should work unless you modified them.

Comment: Hi @Manoj I've just checked the two files you mentioned and they both import the app-variables and app-common files.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake and erroneously put a call to "_app-common.scss" in the login.component.ts file.

This is what caused the problem